# isFullScreenSupported always true for monitors

Tags: java, monitor

Given the following code

```
 GraphicsDevice screen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];
 if (screen.isFullScreenSupported()) {
      //is it always true for monitors?
 }
```

Is `screen.isFullScreenSupported()` always true for monitors?

Comment: Is this just a statement of fact, or do you have a question / problem?

Comment: i want to start application allways in fullscreen, if all monitor support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it may not be true.

The SecurityManager might disallow you the full screen control. Mainly because one could easily fake whole screen in order to grab a password from not-suspecting user (you could mock a bank website).

It can be false:

- in an applet
- in a WebStart Application
- while running in headless mode

JavaDOC of [GraphicsDevice.isFullScreenSupported:](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isFullScreenSupported%28%29)

> Returns true if this GraphicsDevice supports full-screen exclusive
>   mode. If a SecurityManager is installed, its checkPermission method
>   will be called with AWTPermission("fullScreenExclusive").
>   isFullScreenSupported returns true only if that permission is granted