# GraphicsDevice isFullScreenSupported() = false, now what?

Tags: java, graphics, fullscreen

I'm facing the problem, that my Linux machine is returning false, when I check, if fullscreen mode is allowed. Is there a way to bypass this?
I currently use a nasty workaround, where I turn of all decorations and put the window to maximized both, but I really don't like that, since the gnome specific taskbar is still visible.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351936/isfullscreensupported-allways-true-for-monitors) explained, when it usually returns false, but in my case

- it's not an Applet,
- I don't know what a WebStart Application is, so that's probably not my case either
- I'm not running in headless mode.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837719/java-in-full-screen-on-linux-how-to-cover-task-bar) question was, that I have to manage everything on my own, but since it's an older one, I hope this is not the case anymore.

Graphics card:

```
GTX-460 768mb msi
```

java -info gave me:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I use two different kinds of monitors.
**EDIT: Here is the problem. The device does not do fullscreen with two (different) monitors**

```
1920x1080 - BenQ GL2450H
1280x1024 - Samsung (Model unknown)
```

Kernel:

```
Linux Main-PC 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Linux Version:

```
Gnome3, Pinguy OS
Debian
```

Other full screen applications run just fine. Actually I don't know if this is related, but running an old game (supertux), will not support fullscreen as well.

Comment: I would suspect that this comes down more to the OS's capabilities to support FSEM than just your graphics cards capabilities.  It could also be an issue with the version of Java for the OS, as the two need to be able to cooperate in order to achieve this result. Try seeing if the OS and gnome are capable of supporting FSEM first

Comment: Okay, thanks, but how would I do this? I'm able to run Fullscreen applications like steam, without problems, if that is what you mean.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  What version of gnome/linux are you using?  What other research have you done?

Comment: I've searched on google for hours, and only came up with these two links, I posted above. Updated the question for more details.